# Prolog spots in table

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a given list that represent a two dimensional list x. This table contains two "spots" of 1 as you can see in the example below:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xx1111xxxx111xxx
xxx1111xxxx11xxx
x1111xxxxxx111xx
```

I need to change ONLY the second spot from 1 to 2 like the example below:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xx1111xxxx222xxx
xxx1111xxxx22xxx
x1111xxxxxx222xx
```

I need a predicate called `separate(L,M)` that will take the first list L and will produce the second table M

It would be excellent if we can solve this without using any standard predicate like 'findall' etc ...

Comment: It is not clear how these tables are being represented; could you give an example?  Further, how do you determine which "spot" is first and which is second?  And how do you define a "spot"?

Comment: these tables are lists that their elements are lists .The spots are elements that are neighbours and have the value 1 . I want to separate the two spots by turning the elements of the one spot only from 1 to 2

Comment: Nope, no findall, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Definite Clause Grammars (DCG) to implement a finite state transducer. Although DCGs don't deliver much compositional operations on the production side, they are quite good in implementing the recognition side.

So what you want to recognize is two different types of runs of 1's. So basically I guess an input line looks as follows in Extended Backus Naur Form (EBNF):

```
line :== exs run1 exs run2 exs | exs.
exs  :== { "x" } "x".
run1 :== { "1" } "1".
run2 :== { "1" } "1".
```

For the recognition problem you can write a DCG without attributes (what follows is a Prolog text, you can put in a file or directly consult it via ?- [user]):

```
line --> exs, run1, exs, run2, exs | exs.

run1 --> "1", run1.
run1 --> "1".

run2 --> "1", run2.
run2 --> "1".

exs --> "x", exs.
exs --> "x".
```

Here are some example runs:

```
?- phrase(line,"xxx").
Yes 
?- phrase(line,"xxx111xxx111xxx").
Yes 
?- phrase(line,"xxx111xxx"). 
No
```

For the production problem you just can add attributes to the DCG. Using
a difference list works easiest:

```
line(I,O) --> exs(I,H), run1(H,J), exs(J,K), run2(K,L), exs(L,O) | exs(I,O).

run1([0'1|I],O) --> "1", run1(I,O).
run1([0'1|H],H) --> "1".

run2([0'2|I],O) --> "1", run2(I,O).
run2([0'2|H],H) --> "1".

exs([0'x|I],O) --> "x", exs(I,O).
exs([0'x|H],H) --> "x".
```

Here are some example runs:

```
?- phrase(line(R,[]),"xxx").
R = [120, 120, 120] 
?- phrase(line(R,[]),"xxx111xxx111xxx").
R = [120, 120, 120, 49, 49, 49, 120, 120, 120, 50, 50, 50, 120, 120, 120] 
?- phrase(line(R,[]),"xxx111xxx").
No
```

Note: 0' is the Prolog notation for a character code. In ascii we have 0'x = 120, 0'1 = 49, 0'2 = 50, which explains the result. The above should run on most Prolog systems since they support DCGs.

Bye

Definite Clause Grammar
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar

Finite State Transducer
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer

Answer (score 1):

We can apply ad hoc transliteration (just for 'horizontal' lists):

```
transliteration(Matrix, Translit) :-
  maplist(transliteration(not_seen), Matrix, Translit).

transliteration(_State, [], []).
transliteration(State, [X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
  transliteration(State, X, NewState, Y),
  transliteration(NewState, Xs, Ys).

% handle only required state change
transliteration(not_seen, 0'1, seen_first, 0'1).
transliteration(seen_first, C, seen_last, C) :- C =\= 0'1.
transliteration(seen_last, 0'1, seen_last, 0'2).
% catch all, when no change required
transliteration(State, C, State, C).
```

Comment: for this : transliteration([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0]],L).

i get an error

Comment: cat and paste your code give error to me also, but seems there is some strange char in text! If we rewrite, for instance, it's ok...:- transliteration([ [0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0] ], L), writeln(L).
gives [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to solution suggested by @chac, but more direct.

```
walk(L, R) :- walk(s0, L, R).
walk(_, [], []). % finish
walk(s0, [0'1|T], [0'1|R]) :- walk(s1, T, R).
walk(s1, [0'x|T], [0'x|R]) :- walk(s2, T, R).
walk(s2, [0'1|T], [0'2|R]) :- walk(s2, T, R).
walk(S, [H|T], [H|R]) :- walk(S, T, R). % keep state and do nothing
```

Comment: i don't get the right result i gave this : 
walk([[x,x,x,x,x],[x,1,x,x,x],[x,1,x,1,x],[x,x,x,1,x],[x,x,x,x,x]],L).

but i get the same list i gave

Comment: `walk("xxx11xx11x",L).` You should use it for each line. If you are going to use atoms `x` and `1` instead of characters `0'x` and `0'1`. Replace them in appropriate places. Also you may wish to look a bit about Prolog - it's a very interesting language. I wish people to meet it under other circumstances rather than homework...

Comment: I have studied prolog but the teacher's notes do not cover anything about these exercises . And i am trying to see the solution so that i can be ready for the exams. 

when i give walk([0,1,0,0,1,1,1],L) ,i get the answer 'no' . I want the first element of the predicate to be a list  and to turn the second spot to 2

Comment: It should unify `L` with same list as specified in first argument of `walk/2`. If there is no other restrictions on `L` than it shouldn't produce `no`. What kind of Prolog system you are using? I don't think there is something prolog-specific in this exercise except of implementing it in Prolog language. I belive approach used here is called tail-recursive implementation. Each target `walk/3` require reaching other `walk/3` goal until end of list is met. Note that in heads of `walk/3` you'll find with which atoms unification is done (i.e. `0'1` and `0'x` instead of `1` and `0`).

Comment: Ah... Yeah that's kind of finite-state-machine with 3 states and 7 transitions (4 circular - last two rules, 2 - direct 3rd and 4th rule in the middle,  3 terminations - second rule).